# Use jQuery to display column headings and rows from a SQL table

Tags: jquery, sql-server-2008

I am trying to display columns and rows from a SQL Server table using jQuery

I select the tables with `SELECT * FROM table1` so I don't know what the column headings are unless I get them separately from `sys.columns`. The output from the select statement also comes out in XML format to combat XSS.

How I select columns

```
SELECT c.column_id, c.name, y.system_type_id, y.name AS system_type_name
FROM sys.columns AS c
JOIN sys.types AS y ON c.system_type_id = y.system_type_id
JOIN sys.tables AS t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE y.name NOT LIKE 'sysname' 
AND t.object_id = '1234567890'
FOR XML RAW, TYPE, ROOT('rows');
```

A sample XML output

```
<rows>
  <row column_id="1" name="id" system_type_id="56" system_type_name="int" />
  <row column_id="5" name="added" system_type_id="61" system_type_name="datetime" />
  <row column_id="4" name="allowlogin" system_type_id="104" system_type_name="bit" />
  <row column_id="3" name="pw" system_type_id="165" system_type_name="varbinary" />
  <row column_id="2" name="un" system_type_id="231" system_type_name="nvarchar" />
</rows>
```

How I select rows

```
SELECT * FROM table1 FOR XML RAW, TYPE, ROOT('rows')
```

I can't figure out (probably because its late) how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: @marc_s: `XML PATH('')` is not good to use because if you have a column with a name like `<name>` it will break it :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the column names in a single string like this: field1,field2,field3...

If that is the case you could do this:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ','+name FROM YourDatabaseName.sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTableName') ORDER BY column_id FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer Chris but Ive gone down a different route now.